# How do I solve $\int_{-5}^{5} \frac{x^3 \sin^2x}{x^4 +2x^2+1}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-5}^{5} \frac{x^3 \sin^2x}{x^4 +2x^2+1}\,dx$$

I only have basic calculus but this is what I tried.

Firstly this can't be integrated directly.

I tried to make a substitution, letting $u$ equal to varies parts of this expression but to no avail.

I tried integration by parts but it just got too messy.

I did notice that $x^4+2x^2+1 = (x^2+1)^2$ but that didn't get me anywhere either.

I did plot this in Geogebra and noticed that this function is origin-symmetric so $2\int_{0}^{5}f(x)\,dx$ could be used to simplify things after the integration but it doesn't help to do the actual integration.

How does one go about tackling this particular integral?

Comment: Hint: "it's a nice round number".

Comment: $\color{#f00}{\Huge 0}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Let the integrand be $f(x)$.

We have that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, seen by the term $x^3$.

The integral of an odd function from $-a$ to $a$ is $0$.

Comment: Probably you mean $f(x)=-f(\color{red}-x)$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Multiply both sides of your equation by $-1$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Ohh! I am so dumb. My brain was on vacation writing that.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I can relate lol

Comment: my brain's still on vacation @JaideepKhare

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

It is an odd function, so the integration should be 0

Answer (score 6):

The function under integral is odd so

> $$\\ \int _{ -5 }^{ 5 } \frac { { x }^{ 3 }\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ x^{ 4 }+2x^{ 2 }+1 } dx=\int _{ -5 }^{ 5 } \frac { { x }^{ 3 }\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ { \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } dx=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^3\sin^2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$.

Since $f(-x)=-f(x)$, we obtain:
$$\int_{-5}^5f(x)dx=\int_{-5}^0f(x)dx+\int_{0}^5f(x)dx=$$
$$=\int_{-5}^0\left(-f(-x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^5f(x)dx=$$
$$=\int_{0}^5f(-x)dx+\int_{0}^5f(x)dx=$$
$$=\int_{0}^5\left(f(-x)+f(x)\right)dx=0.$$